# Special Character Count issue in Client System

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, streamwriter

We have an exe which extracts data from various tables in our database and write them to a text/csv file. This file is subsequently fetch by client system for internal purposes.

While loading this txt/csv file,they are getting this error -
The string "Hexxx Sxxxff ber das Axxen von JM ixxxt und zxxx P" has a length of 65 and the field has a maximum length of 64.

The issue is that at their end, special character count (eg.for Á , Ô) as are considered as 2 whereas at our end its giving the correct count 1,which results in count mismatch. We both have followed UTF8 encoding all across the exe.

What would be the best solution to avoid this? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Can you post a sample string that goes wrong, along with expected and actual counts?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that they are trying to insert the extracted data to database. Then the problem may be related with the collation / encoding of their database.